# To set the positions of items in spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I am populating my spinner from database. I have a collection of mobile brands. I have added "Add a new brand" also... But when I am setting the spinner items from DB, it comes in somewhere middle.. I want it to go at the end.. Can i do it? if yes, how? please help, thanks in advance.

```
Spinner brand;
brand=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_brand);
private void loadSpinnerData() {
    // database handler
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> Brand = db.getBrands();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Brand);



    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    brand.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Comment: have you add this "Add a new brand" from database ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana in previous activity, i am adding "add new brand".. and in this activity, i am retrieving this from same. is there any way that i load all spinner items from database but only one item statically?

Answer (score 0):

Add time column in your brand table and on querying sort by time. So, you will get last added item at last in spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ArrayList and add all your database items to it. and then add your "Choose a brand" string to it. and then pass the ArrayList to Spinner.

Although I should warn you, you are "probably" doing it wrong. If you add "Choose a brand" item to spinner, it will also be selectable, which you might not want :)